# Add mathjax support to a (local) ikiwiki

Tags: installation, wiki, mathjax, ikiwiki

Is there a way to add mathjax support to ikiwiki? If so, how to proceed step by step (in linux) to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install pandoc (> 1.8)
- Get the latest pandoc-iki plugin: `cd /tmp/; git clone https://github.com/dubiousjim/pandoc-iki.git`
- find out where pandoc is installed: `which pandoc` for example `/usr/bin/pandoc`
- add the following lines to your wiki - setup (e.g. mywiki.setup) file:

  ```
  # pandoc plugin

  pandoc_command => "/usr/bin/pandoc",

  pandoc_latex => 1,

  pandoc_rst => 0,

  pandoc_math => "mathjax",
  ```
- add `pandoc` to your plugin list in your setup file, for example

  ```
   \# plugins to add to the default configuration

  add_plugins => [qw{goodstuff websetup wmd pandoc}]
  ```
- `sudo cp /tmp/pandoc-iki/mathjax.tmpl /usr/share/ikiwiki/templates/page.tmpl`
- `sudo cp /tmp/pandoc-iki/pandoc.pm /usr/share/perl5/IkiWiki/Plugin`
- `sudo ikiwiki --setup ~/mywiki.setup`
- To activate html_css you change the following line in `/usr/share/ikiwiki/templates/page.tmpl`:

  `<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>`

  to

  `<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>`

  then do `sudo ikiwiki --setup ~/mywiki.setup` again.
- If you want to use your ikiwiki offline too, you could change the path to the directory: download mathjax and put it somewhere for example into `/var/www/myiki` and do in change the line above to

  ```
  <script src="/iki/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"   type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```

  (don't forget to run `ikiwiki --setup`)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).